# Nested function in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-props

Does anyone know what is correct syntax for styled-components?

```
const TextWithDropCap = styled.div`
    ${(props: TextProps) => props.hasDropCap && `
        & > p:first-child:first-letter {
            float: left;
            font-size: calc(${themeHelper(theme.text.size.10)} * 3)
            lineHeight: calc(${themeHelper(theme.text.size.15)} * 3)
        }
    `};
`;
```

Because right now it does not evaluate the inner function and it only renders it as a string. This is css that styled components generates for it:

```
.NbsOb > p:first-child:first-letter{
    float:left;
    font-size:calc(function (styledComponentProps) {
         return exports.getThemeProp(styledComponentProps,propertyPath);
    }
     * 3);
    lineHeight:calc(function (styledComponentProps) {
         return exports.getThemeProp(styledComponentProps,propertyPath);
    }
     * 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your styled-components syntax is a bit off...

try this:

```
const TextWithDropCap = styled.div`
    ${props => props.hasDropCap && css`
        & > p::first-letter  {
            float: left;
            font-size: calc(${themeHelper(theme.text.size.10)} * 3)
            lineHeight: calc(${themeHelper(theme.text.size.15)} * 3)
        }
    `}
`;
```

Check this article for more info: 
https://blog.alexdevero.com/introduction-styled-components/
https://www.styled-components.com/

Hope this helps